# How to iterate on table columns in SQL based on a value?

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, while-loop, dynamic-sql

I have a table say TABLE A which has 12 columns like below:

Point1
Point2
Point3
Point4
Point5 ..Point12

Now I have to run an update on my table based on a limit that I will get from another table TABLE B and then shift the values of these columns accordingly

What I want to do is that

If limit = 1

```
Point1 = 0
```

if the limit from Table B is say 3
Then I want to do the following:

```
Point3 = Point2
Point2 = Point1
Point1 = 0
```

Similarly if the limit is say 6 then following should happen

```
Point6 = Point5
Point5 = Point4
Point4 = Point3
Point3 = Point2
Point2 = Point1
Point1 = 0
```

The limit can be from 1 to 12

Now hardcoding the values like above is the last thing that I would do. 
How can I achieve this using SQL dynamically using loops?

Comment: What have you done yourself already? Even if you have hardcoded it, can you show some code?

Comment: Gordon, this is data pertaining to 1 single row i.e. of one sinlge record. This data cannot be transformed from columns to rows

Comment: The Idea is to shift the values from the lower value Point column to the higher value point column

Comment: @geekstudent how that data might work in rows:http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/751270/positions-as-rows-not-columns this doesn't fully answer your question but explains a little more of the suggestion (i hope :D)

Comment: @geekstudent i improved that example http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/751270/positions-as-rows-not-columns - not saying this is the best use of this technique, just trying to aid discussion

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1,1)
   ,[Point1] INT
   ,[Point2] INT
   ,[Point3] INT
   ,[Point4] INT
   ,[Point5] INT
   ,[Point6] INT
   ,[Point7] INT
   ,[Point8] INT
   ,[Point9] INT
   ,[Point10] INT
   ,[Point11] INT
   ,[Point12] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Point1], [Point2], [Point3], [Point4], [Point5], [Point6], [Point7], [Point8], [Point9], [Point10], [Point11], [Point12])
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);


DECLARE @Limit TINYINT = 5;

UPDATE @DataSource
SET [Point1] = IIF(@Limit >= 1, 0, [Point1])
   ,[Point2] = IIF(@Limit >= 2, [Point1], [Point2])
   ,[Point3] = IIF(@Limit >= 3, [Point2], [Point3])
   ,[Point4] = IIF(@Limit >= 4, [Point3], [Point4])
   ,[Point5] = IIF(@Limit >= 5, [Point4], [Point5])
   ,[Point6] = IIF(@Limit >= 6, [Point5], [Point6])
   ,[Point7] = IIF(@Limit >= 7, [Point6], [Point7])
   ,[Point8] = IIF(@Limit >= 8, [Point7], [Point8])
   ,[Point9] = IIF(@Limit >= 9, [Point8], [Point9])
   ,[Point10] = IIF(@Limit >= 10, [Point9], [Point10])
   ,[Point11] = IIF(@Limit >= 11, [Point10], [Point11])
   ,[Point12] = IIF(@Limit >= 12, [Point11], [Point12])

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;
```

Another technique will be to use dynamic T-SQL statement in order to update only the columns you need and to exclude this `IIF` statements. If you are using `SQL Version` under `2012` you must switch the `IIF` with `CASE WHEN` statements:

```
UPDATE @DataSource
SET [Point1] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 1 THEN 0 ELSE [Point1] END
   ,[Point2] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 2 THEN [Point1] ELSE [Point2] END
   ,[Point3] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 3 THEN [Point2] ELSE [Point3] END
   ,[Point4] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 4 THEN [Point3] ELSE [Point4] END
   ,[Point5] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 5 THEN [Point4] ELSE [Point5] END
   ,[Point6] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 6 THEN [Point5] ELSE [Point6] END
   ,[Point7] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 7 THEN [Point6] ELSE [Point7] END
   ,[Point8] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 8 THEN [Point7] ELSE [Point8] END
   ,[Point9] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 9 THEN [Point8] ELSE [Point9] END
   ,[Point10] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 10 THEN [Point9] ELSE [Point10] END
   ,[Point11] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 11 THEN [Point10] ELSE [Point11] END
   ,[Point12] = CASE WHEN @Limit >= 12 THEN [Point11] ELSE [Point12] END
```